# Pandas group all aggregates smaller then x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I'm trying to find a way to do a more advanced group by aggregate in pandas. For example:

```
d = {'name': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'amount': [2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 2, 4, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_per_category = df.groupby(['name']) \
                             .agg({'amount': ['count',  'sum']}) \
                             .sort_values(by=[('amount', 'count')], ascending=False)

df_per_category[('amount', 'sum')].plot.barh()
df_per_category
```

Produces:

|  | amount |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | count | sum |
| Name |  |  |
| b | 3 | 12 |
| a | 2 | 7 |
| c | 1 | 2 |
| d | 1 | 4 |
| e | 1 | 1 |

When you have a dataset where 70% of items have just one count and 30% have multiple counts it would be nice if you could group the 70%. At first to begin simple, simply group all the records that have just one count and put them under a name like `other`. So the result would look like:

|  | amount |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | count | sum |
| Name |  |  |
| b | 3 | 12 |
| a | 2 | 7 |
| other | 3 | 7 |

Is there a panda's way to do this? Right now I'm thinking of just looping trough my aggregate result and creating a new dataframe manually.

Current solution:

```
name = []
count = []
amount = []

aggregates = {
    5: [0, 0],
    10: [0, 0],
    25: [0, 0],
    50: [0, 0],
}
l = list(aggregates)
first_aggregates = l
last_aggregate = l[-1] + 1
aggregates.update({last_aggregate: [0, 0]})

def aggregate_small_values(c):
    n = c.name    
    s = c[('amount', 'sum')]
    c = c[('amount', 'count')]

    if c <= 2:
    
        if s < last_aggregate:
            for a in first_aggregates:
                if s <= a:
                    aggregates[a][0] += c
                    aggregates[a][1] += s
                    break
        else:
            aggregates[last_aggregate][0] += c
            aggregates[last_aggregate][1] += s
    else:
        name.append(n)
        count.append(c)
        amount.append(s)

df_per_category.apply(aggregate_small_values, axis=1)

for a in first_aggregates:
    name.append(f'{a} and smaller')
    count.append(aggregates[a][0])
    amount.append(aggregates[a][1])

name.append(f'{last_aggregate} and bigger')
count.append(aggregates[last_aggregate][0])
amount.append(aggregates[last_aggregate][1])

df_agg = pd.DataFrame(index=name, data={'count': count, 'amount': amount})

df_agg.plot.barh(title='Boodschappen 2021')

df_agg
```

yields something like:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your solution to question? 70% is count from what values in sample?

Comment: Nice tables....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need replace `name` by `other` if counts is `1` use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

```
df.loc[~df['name'].duplicated(keep=False), 'name'] = 'other'
print (df)
    name  amount
0      a       2
1      a       5
2      b       2
3      b       3
4      b       7
5  other       2
6  other       4
7  other       1
```

If need replace by percenteges, here below `20%` is set `other` use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True` and then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for mask with same size like original `df`:

```
s = df['name'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print (s)
b    0.375
a    0.250
d    0.125
e    0.125
c    0.125
Name: name, dtype: float64

df.loc[df['name'].map(s).lt(0.2), 'name'] = 'other'
print (df)
    name  amount
0      a       2
1      a       5
2      b       2
3      b       3
4      b       7
5  other       2
6  other       4
7  other       1
```

For filter by counts, here below `3`:

```
s = df['name'].value_counts()
print (s)
b    3
a    2
d    1
e    1
c    1
Name: name, dtype: int64

df.loc[df['name'].map(s).lt(3), 'name'] = 'other'
print (df)
    name  amount
0  other       2
1  other       5
2      b       2
3      b       3
4      b       7
5  other       2
6  other       4
7  other       1
```

Comment: given my original question this is a good solution. It is also shot and simple, thanks fot that. However if you look at my current code (i added it to the question), I aggregate on multiple max values over multiple columns. Haha, sorry to make it even more complex. Could you elaborate further on how to handle a more complex aggregate.  Anyway I shall approve your answer since it does what the original question was about.